# Postgres.app: pg_restore hangs

Tags: macos, postgresql, osx-mountain-lion, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to troubleshoot the `pg_restore` command on my system. I've installed [Postgresapp](http://postgresapp.com/), and I've [included its binaries on my PATH](http://postgresapp.com/documentation#toc_1). Commands such as `psql` and `pg_dump` appear to work fine, and running `which pg_restore` give the expected result.

```
$ which pg_restore
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/pg_restore
```

The problem is that `pg_restore` doesn't seem to do anything. When I run it in the terminal, no output is printed, eiher to the console or to the [logs](http://codeinthehole.com/writing/configuring-logging-for-postgresapp/).  This is true no matter what arguments I pass in, including the `--verbose` switch. Running it does cause a pg_restore process to appear in my activity monitor, but this process doesn't use any CPU. Apart from that, nothing happens at all.

Has anyone else seen this issue?  Do you have any suggestions for getting `pg_restore` to work?

Comment: How much data are you trying to restore? Typically pg_restore doesn't output anything until its done, unless there are errors or warnings, unless you specify --verbose mode.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

The command I was running included an extra line break after the user name.

As in, I was trying to execute this

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myusername
-d mydb latest.dump
```

instead of this

```
pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myusername -d mydb latest.dump
```

For some reason that extra linebreak was gumming things up. Once I removed it pg_restore worked properly.

Answer (score 22):

I got a hint from [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59694418/14269772); the `-f` option doesn't do what you might think it does (or what I thought it does, anyway ), even if you're using a "custom" format dump (i.e. not one which you provide with shell redirection like `|` or `>`).

- Incorrect ❌: `pg_restore -f filename.dump` – waits for a series of commands from STDIN, restoring to a database in `filename.dump`
- Correct ✅: `pg_restore -d database filename.dump` – restores `filename.dump` to `database`.

I thought for some reason that a custom dump included the database name so you didn't need to provide it at all.

Comment: Feeling so dumb right now.  I waited for the whole 4-hour thinking the dump is bigger and that's why it's taking so much time.

Answer (score 1):

I was also stuck for no reason. I changed from `pg_restore -U seed -h localhost -p 5432 -f dump.backup -C --verbose` to `pg_restore -d seed -U seed -h localhost -p 5432 < dump.backup` and it worked.

If this can help someone..

Answer (score 0):

sometimes if you have long running queries you need to stop it so pg_restore will not get stuck.

Run this script:

```
SELECT pg_cancel_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE state = 'active' and pid <> pg_backend_pid();
```

[https://www.sqlprostudio.com/blog/8-killing-cancelling-a-long-running-postgres-query#:~:text=Terminate%20all%20queries,be%20used%20in%20special%20situations](https://www.sqlprostudio.com/blog/8-killing-cancelling-a-long-running-postgres-query#:%7E:text=Terminate%20all%20queries,be%20used%20in%20special%20situations).